# Pegar item selecionado em um NSMenu em Swift

Tags: swift

Estou usando o AMPathPopUpButton para salvar um arquivo de texto, mas o problema é que eu não consigo pegar a pasta selecionada pelo usuário. O código está assim:

```
import Cocoa;
class SaveFile: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lista: NSMenu!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {

        }
    }

    @IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {

        //pegar valor aqui

    }
}
```